# Do you either put comma before conjunction so or not?

Tags: conjunctions

> [M-W Learner’s](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/so)
>   We were bored with the movie, so we left.
>   I don't want to go, so I won't.
>   There are no more chairs available, so you'll have to stand.
>
> [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/so_3)
>   It was still painful so I went to see a doctor.

There are commas in M-W Learner’s examples before *so*; in OALD isn't. Is it a different way to write in two countries, or either way do you, American and British, can write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original purpose of punctuation conventions in manuscripts was to show readers where naturally occurring syntactic pauses appeared. These marks acted as clause-divisions and phrase demarcations.  Punctuation marks should continue to serve the same purpose.

Since there is a naturally occurring syntactic pause after the word "painful" in the following statement, a comma would be appropriate there:

**It was still painful, so I went to see a doctor.**

On the other hand, there would be hardly any pause after the word "doctor" in this statement, so no comma is needed there:

**I went to see a doctor because it was still painful.**

Answer (score 1):

I am not a native speaker but I think there's no need of a *comma* in the OALD example *because* keeping *pause* there actually takes off the *seriousness* of seeing a doctor! If I'm not wrong, *comma* actually introduces a *little* pause.

Said that,

> We were bored with the movie.........so we left ~ okay 
>  I don't want to go.......so  I won't ~ okay 
>  There are no more chairs available......so you'll have to stand ~ okay, as well!

But then...

> It was still painful.......so I went to see a doctor -does not introduce the 'impact'

over...

> It was still painful so I went to see a doctor.

Something like...

> I did not find my baby in the crib **so** I shouted...